# Firestore security rules: why can I read the data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore collection called myusers where I have approx 200 documents with information on the users, ie email, name, etc. The document Id is the firebase uid.

I have set the following security rule

```js
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        
        function isRestaurant() {
            return request.auth.uid == 'agivenuser' || request.auth.uid == 'anothergivenuser';
          }
    
        match /myusers/{user} {
          allow read: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid || isRestaurant();
          allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
            
            match /mytok/{doc}/{document=**} {
                allow read: if request.auth.uid == user || isRestaurant();
                allow create: if request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
            }   
        }
      }
```

Now I have tried to log in with a user which does not make isRestaurant() true and it looks like this user can access the entire **myusers** collection. I thought that `resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid` would basically make the user to see only the document where his **uid** matches with the **userId** field of the given document. In reality he can see the entire collection and all the documents within it.

Note that when I attempt to read the collection using getDocuments(), then I am not able to read any document but if I create a stream, it looks like I am able to read everything.

This is my code for the get document (which fails to read the collection)

```
  void check() async {    
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection('myusers').getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    documents.forEach((element) {
      print(element['email']);
    });
```

And this is the code with the StreamBuilder (which make me print all the email of each document in the collection)

```
    Stream myStream;
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      myStream = _firestore.collection('myusers').snapshots();
    }
```

```js
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: myStream,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return new Text(
                            'Loading...',
                            style: kSendButtonTextStyle.copyWith(color: kColorText),
                          );
                        default:
                          customerDB = snapshot.data.documents;
                          snapshot.data.documents.forEach((element) {
                            print(element['email']);
                          });
                          return new ListView(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                            children: customerDB.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                                child: Card(
                                  color: kColorPrimaryLight,
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    title: Text(
                                      (document['userName'] ?? 'xxx'), 
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          );
                      }
                    },
                  )
                ]),
              ),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*In reality any user can see the entore collection and all the document within it.*" - how did you reach that conclusion?  What have you done to prove this?  Please edit the question to explain fully.

Comment: Hi Doug, I have added some more context. it looks like as a user I am able to read the entire collection and not only the document in the collection where userId = to the uid

Comment: Your code uses a collection called "myuser", but your rules say "myusers".

Comment: typo corrected thanks

Comment: Hi Doug, do you see any mistakes in my code? a given user can access all the documents in the collection "myusers" while I would like he will access only his document (= theone where the field "userId" is equal to the uid)

Answer (score 0):

Any user matching `resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid` **OR** `isRestaurant()` will be able to read the resource.

Please confirm that you are not using the users that make `isRestaurant` evaluate to true.

Comment: Hi there, yes I am not using a user that makes isRestaurant true

Comment: Hello, I have added a few additional information. I am really shocked that a simple user can read all my data in that collection. My intent is to give access to all data to the user in the isRestaurant() but restrict all the others to see only 1 document, ie his own document

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

this will allow any authenticated user to create new data but only users who owns the document can modify that document.

Comment: I have used the code you propose and I keep having the same problem (my collection is called myusers). If I am logged in as a user I can read the entire user collection. It happens I can read the data if I use a streambuilder. It does not allow me to read the user collection if I use Firestore.instance.collection('myusers').getDocuments();

Comment: it's not possibe. you are doing something wrong then. this rule above will allow only users that created a document to modify that document but you need to make sure that the document id is same as user id

Comment: I agree I am doing something wrong but I don't know what. The reality is that when I run the app in the simulator I am actually able to read the entire collection, ie any user can the email of all the users. I am shocked by this and I am non sure how this is possible. What do you think can make it happening? I have the added my flutter code with the streambuilder above